SwiftUI Preview and code breaks when adding multiple entries to SwiftData model instance
I have two SwiftData models called User -> HealthRate one to many relations. When trying to add multiple heart rates to the user the preview crashes but when adding only one it seems to work. See my preview code below:
#Preview {
    ...
    let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: User.self, configurations: config)
    let user = User(name: "FFF", birthDate: dateSevenYearsAgo()!, gender: .male)
    let heartRateEntryHigh = HeartRateEntry(heartRate: 78, measurementDate: .now, activity: .resting)
    let heartRateEntryMedium = HeartRateEntry(heartRate: 72, measurementDate: .now.addingTimeInterval(-60), activity: .resting)
    let heartRateEntryLow = HeartRateEntry(heartRate: 45, measurementDate: .now, activity: .resting)
    
    user.heartRates.append(heartRateEntryHigh)
    user.heartRates.append(heartRateEntryMedium)
    user.heartRates.append(heartRateEntryLow)
    container.mainContext.insert(user)
    return DetailView().modelContainer(container)
}

The question is why adding multiple hear rates breaks the code?

The reason why it breaks is because I have added the heart rates before inserting the user. When inserting the user first and then adding the heart rates it will fix the issue.
#Preview {
    ...
    let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: User.self, configurations: config)
    let user = User(name: "FFF", birthDate: dateSevenYearsAgo()!, gender: .male)
    
    #### HERE WE ADD THE USER #####
    container.mainContext.insert(user) 
    
    let heartRateEntryHigh = HeartRateEntry(heartRate: 78, measurementDate: .now, activity: .resting)
    let heartRateEntryMedium = HeartRateEntry(heartRate: 72, measurementDate: .now.addingTimeInterval(-60), activity: .resting)
    let heartRateEntryLow = HeartRateEntry(heartRate: 45, measurementDate: .now, activity: .resting)
    
    #### HERE WE ADD THE HEAR RATES ####
    user.heartRates.append(heartRateEntryHigh)  
    user.heartRates.append(heartRateEntryMedium)
    user.heartRates.append(heartRateEntryLow)
    return DetailView().modelContainer(container)
}

No idea why this is but I think it probably has to do with conflicting identifiers when creating a heart rate before the other one has been saved. But if someone could explain it would be good to know.
